# I want to run a Dropbox-like service on my server. What's the best Free solution available?

Tags: file-sharing, synchronization, dropbox

It's for a relatively small group of people (unlikely to exceed 30). I'd like it to work as much as Dropbox as possible, i.e., user runs a program in the background, and it syncs a local folder's files with one on the server.

Filesystem-like access to remote files won't do -- it has to be a synchronization program like Dropbox.

Comment: The free version comes with 2GB of space. Do you need more?

Comment: If it was free and easy everyone would do it. They've got the secret sauce, which is why they can charge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [SparkleShare](http://sparkleshare.org/) - an open-source alternative to Dropbox which is built on Git.

Unfortunately it is only available for Linux and Mac OS at this point in time.

Answer (score 0):

May be rsync? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync

Comment: don't understand why this was down-voted... rsync is a very reasonable, secure and fast solution... if people are going to down-vote at least provide a reason...